# WEB API Self Hosting in Server

Tags: asp.net-web-api, owin, self-host-webapi

i have created ASP.net WEB API and hosted using OWIN and windows service,
i have hosted the service in windows Server 2014 r2 using INSTALLUTILL , The service is running properly.

My problem is when ever i browse the API using Localhost(localhost:51495/api/User/GetAllUsers), i'm able to see the data . But when i'm using the Host Name(HostName:51495/api/User/GetAllUsers) i'm getting error saying . bad host and sometimes Service unavailable .

I know i'm missing something to map host-name with the localhost but not sure how to do it. Please help me with this.

Comment: You can solve this by hosting the api in IIS

Comment: i dont want to use IIS because its lightweight API and i dont need the features if API

Comment: was this ever resolved Naveen?

Comment: yes i need to hard code the Host name during hosting. I know this is not the rite solution , But it worked